# OpenSearch Dashboard Query Language

Tags: dql, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, wazuh

How to derive "enabled":false part from the data.representation filed using DQL (Opensearch Dashboard Query Language)

The log as below

data.representation
{"enabled":false,"totp":false,"emailverified":false,"}}

I have tried the following without any success

location : "/opt/wazuh/keycloak/admin.log" and data.representation :"enabled":false

location : "/opt/wazuh/keycloak/admin.log" and data.representation : {enabled:false}

location : "/opt/wazuh/keycloak/admin.log" and data.representation : *"enabled":false*